# Is is possible to send solr json data rather than index the file?

Tags: solr

The code below is to index the file:

```
 bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/*.xml
```

if i want to just send the solr some json data , solr store these data and let me search , it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can index JSON data.**

If you want to index json data from file, file extension must be .json or you have to provide file type with `-type application/json` param

Sample JSON file data.json to index :

```
[
  {
    "id": "100",
    "author": [
      "ashraful",
      "chayon"
    ],
    "body": "Sample 100"
  },
  {
    "id": "200",
    "author": [
      "ashraful"
    ],
    "body": "Sample 200"
  }
]
```

post command to index the data.json file  :
i.e

```
bin/post -c test data.json
```

Or

```
bin/post -c test -type application/json data.json
```

If you want to index json data directly without using file, then you have to escape your json data and use `-d "your_json_data"` as argument.

i.e

```
bin/post -c test -type application/json -d "[{\"id\":\"101\",\"author\":[\"ashraful\",\"chayon\"],\"body\":\"Sample 101\"}, {\"id\":\"200\",\"author\":[\"ashraful\"],\"body\":\"Sample 200\"}]"
```

Comment: thanks bro , but when i try to index json data, is it possible to use the loop to index ?

Comment: use can create a shell script for that

Comment: sry , i am not very familiar with unix , do you have any example to use the loop to index ?

Comment: Why do you need loop ? for multiple file index ??

Comment: I have many json data to index , if input one by one , it is very complex

Comment: Put all your json data into a json file, then just index the file using my first command